# Struts2 PermGen Out of Memory error

Tags: java, tomcat, struts2, out-of-memory, permgen

I noticed this occurrence in big application where the front end server was gobbling up PermGen quite fast, worst part it kept on increasing on every request, sometimes it just keeps on increasing even though we don't do any request to the application server at all. I faced this with tomcat 6.0.33, tomcat6.0.29 both.

To isolate the problem I picked up struts blank and to my dismay it was showing the same trend. Is this normal? 
I tried checking out a few version of struts2 like 2.2.1, 2.2.1.1,  2.2.3.1 using maven (mvn archetype:generate) and after running them in jetty, I noticed that the PermGen space is filled up in every request by 2-3KB. I am testing on struts blank and jetty-6.1.21.

Since PermGen is increasing as a function of number of request I suspect how much worthy is it to go to production with it?

Comment: 1. Does calling this multiple times in web apps cause PermGen space to go up? `inst = Class.forName("com.xxx.yyy.MyClass").newInstance(); ... inst = null;` 2. Does this class gets unloaded and garbage collected later?

Comment: without any details about your profiler details its really hard for anyone to say anything.

Comment: @Umesh What I wanted to know is if there is any known issue related to struts-2. And also if you can answer if the above senario inst = Class.forName("com.xxx.yyy.MyClass").newInstance(); ... inst = null; likely to cause PermGen space memory leak.

Comment: regarding performance issue there was few with OGNL but that was with older version of struts2, i am not sure which version you are using in your application.Still refer [performance-tuning](http://struts.apache.org/2.3.1/docs/performance-tuning.html).Regarding the `inst = Class.forName("com.xxx.yyy.MyClass").newInstance(); ... inst = null;` where you are using this? my original vote still with `hvgotcodes` only real profiler dump can help in further analysis

Comment: @Umesh Thanks for performance tuning link. `inst = Class.forName("com.xxx.yyy.MyBusinessClass").newInstance(); ... inst = null;` This is not part of struts, for every request I am dynamically selecting which business class to execute and instantiates them.

Comment: that was just a generic tuning page and as said by other show your profiler output data only than some one can help you in this regard.

Comment: How do you measure PermGen usage?

Comment: to measure PermGen usage jvisualizer that comes with jdk, or write a small jsp to [dump jvm parameters](http://www.smartsoftwarebits.com/qaa/46-misc/83-how-to-monitor-java-memory-utilization-in-different-generations-in-tomcat), or try some paid tools like your kit.

Answer (score 4):

The only way to know for sure is to attach a profiler and look at which classes are taking up the most memory, and try to find a memory leak.  You can configure you jvm to dump the heap on crash, and load the resulting file into a profiler to look at the state of the heap when it crashed.

Struts is used in many production web apps.  I think it is more likely a problem with your app.